# cannot import name 'Option' from 'discord' error in Heroku deployment

Tags: python, heroku, discord, discord.py

this is the error i am getting on the heroku logs

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Option' from 'discord' (/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/__init__.py)
```

this is my requirements.txt file:

```
git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py@master
git+https://github.com/Pycord-Development/pycord
PyNaCl==1.3.0
pandas
dnspython==1.16.0
async-timeout==3.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

in the app environment run

pip install git+https://github.com/Pycord-Development/pycord

my python version 3.8